# java - How to do unidirectional one-to-many relationship in Ebean

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a unidirectional relationship where one entity has a list of another entity (one to many) .

I have set cascade type to CascadeType.ALL,
And i am getting error

```
[PersistenceException: Error inserting bean [class models.User$Activity] with unidirectional relationship. For inserts you must use cascade save on the master bean [class models.User].]
```

at this line

```
userForm.get().update(id);
```

I want to update existing user entry.If i replaced above line by

```
userForm.get().save();
```

It creates duplicate entry.Is there any solution.Please help me.
My code :

```
@Valid
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Activity> activities;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a lot of trouble with @OneToMany relationships with Ebean. I've also experienced this error message several times.
I think you need to have a bidirectional relationship between your entities.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer above correctly solves the problem: making relationships bidirectional. An example is available in this [link](http://blog.xebia.com/jpa-implementation-patterns-bidirectional-assocations/)